# Render partial in two columns using bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <%= render @buildings %>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I render the above in two columns?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">1st column</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">2nd column</div>
</div>
```

Preferably in horizontal order i.e.

> 1, 2, 3, 4

becomes

```
1,2 
3,4
```

**_building.html.erb**

`<% building.image %>`

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <% @buildings.each_slice(2) do |(b1, b2)| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"><%= render b1 %></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><%= render b2 if b2 %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Since it's a view, perhaps you should create a custom css class that utilizes 50% width.